# CreateStateObject returns E_INVALIDARG - How to figure out what precisely the cause is?

Tags: directx, raytracing

I'm trying to compile and run the code published on https://github.com/boksajak/referencePT of the reference path tracer described in [Raytracing Gems II](https://www.realtimerendering.com/raytracinggems/rtg2/). It is based on https://github.com/acmarrs/IntroToDXR. Unfortunately, while the latter is working, the former is not. The call `d3d.device->CreateStateObject(&pipelineDesc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&dxr.rtpso));` in `CreatePipelineStateObject` (see https://github.com/boksajak/referencePT/blob/2cb5fb986ab8734bcaf52c048f8b6b5895e9ce5f/src/Graphics.cpp#L1468) is return `E_INVALIDARG`? From the output window, I can see that two exceptions are thrown:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC5860CF19 in ReferencePT_d.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0000007C766FD798.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC5860CF19 in ReferencePT_d.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0000007C766FD7B8.
```

The suboject descriptions seem totally fine to me. I have no idea what the actual cause is. Do I have any possibility to get a more detailed error description?

In the `CreateDevice` function, the debug layer is enabled. I've even tried to enable further validation by using the following code instead:

```
void CreateDevice(D3D12Global &d3d)
{
    uint32_t dxgiFactoryFlags = 0;

#if defined(_DEBUG)
    // Enable the D3D12 debug layer.
    {
        if (SUCCEEDED(D3D12GetDebugInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&d3d.debugController))))
        {
            d3d.debugController->EnableDebugLayer();
            d3d.debugController->SetEnableGPUBasedValidation(TRUE);
        }

        dxgiFactoryFlags |= DXGI_CREATE_FACTORY_DEBUG;

        ComPtr<IDXGIInfoQueue> infoQueue;
        if (SUCCEEDED(DXGIGetDebugInterface1(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(infoQueue.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()))))
        {
            infoQueue->SetBreakOnSeverity(DXGI_DEBUG_ALL, DXGI_INFO_QUEUE_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_ERROR, true);
            infoQueue->SetBreakOnSeverity(DXGI_DEBUG_ALL, DXGI_INFO_QUEUE_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_CORRUPTION, true);
        }
    }
#endif

    // Create a DXGI Factory
    HRESULT hr = CreateDXGIFactory2(dxgiFactoryFlags, IID_PPV_ARGS(&d3d.factory));
    Utils::Validate(hr, L"Error: failed to create DXGI factory!");

    ...
```

However, I still don't get a more verbose output.

Comment: The exceptions thrown are useless, this is just how many Microsoft Windows layers do error handling nowadays (throw 1st chance + catch all by internal code, usually, otherwise it would crash). This code builds and runs successfully on my PC (although it outputs lots of warnings in the debug output...), I have an NVidia card, not sure it's mandatory or not but this is NVidia code... Can you confirm you do see some warnings in the debug output?

Comment: @SimonMourier I also have a NVIDIA card. And I don't get any warnings. I only noticed that I got three "Poco::NotFoundException"s which are thrown before. I just checked and they are also thrown in the "IntroToDxr" code, which is working well at the end.

Comment: Since the app is enabled for debug layer, you should see some DirectX/DXGI warnings when you debug under Visual Studio in the ouput window. Have you *installed* the debug layer? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/installing-the-direct2d-debug-layer this is what I get when I run the app https://pastebin.com/raw/G25DmFpM (see D3D12 WARNING)

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, of course. The debug layer is working well in other of my programs.

Comment: What's exactly your video card model?

Comment: On D3D12CreateDevice what D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL exactly you request and get?

Comment: Just checked on local PC, works just fine. Make sure you have recent versions of Windows and SDK installed; some features require the recent versions.

Comment: @SimonMourier I've just figured out that the reason for the failure is in the PathTracer.hlsl. When I remove the line `payload.uvs = float16_t2(vertex.uv);` from the closesthit shader, then its working. My guess is that the type `float16_t2` is not supported. I've tried to google what it is, but can't find anything. My guess is that it is a type consisting of a 2-tuple of 8-bit floats? Maybe I can replace it by something equivalent.

Comment: `float16_t` is supposed to be supported with HLSL shader model 6.2 (Windows 10 / 1803+) https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler/wiki/16-Bit-Scalar-Types the graphics.cpp file in the project does add the `enable-16bit-types` flags to compilation. You mean you can compile the shader (compilerInfo.compiler->Compile(...) in graphics) but it fails after that?

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, it fails at pipeline creation (that is, at the `CreateStateObject` call with `E_INVALIDARG`). But shader compilation before succeeded.